# Pyplot stacked bars with dates

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

First of all - sorry for the too general question, but I didn't find good example of the code that I am looking for.

I have a DF similar to:

| Customer | Size | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Customer1 | 5 | 01.01.2021 |
| Customer2 | 2 | 01.01.2021 |
| Customer3 | 6 | 01.01.2021 |
| Customer1 | 5 | 02.01.2021 |
| Customer2 | 4 | 02.01.2021 |
| Customer3 | 5 | 02.01.2021 |

Basically I have some customers using specific amount of storage per day.
I need a stacked bar plot, where each bar is a single day, and the sections of each bar are the customers. I plan to have 30 days history, placed in a single chart, which means 30 bars with their X number of sections.

No need to have visual space between the bars.

Thank you!

Comment: Run `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])` first. Then try `df.pivot(index='Date', columns='Customer', values='Size').plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)`

Comment: Thank you.
I received

**ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape**

It's normal for the date column to have duplicates, because the DF contains data from multiple customers on the same date.

Comment: You must have duplicate values for both Date and Customer. Try `df[df.duplicated(subset=['Date', 'Customer'], keep=False)]` to check if this is the case. Try de-duping or aggregating on these 2 fields to fix the data.

Comment: Yes. I found my problem. Now everything works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform your dataframe before plot *as suggested by @ChrisAdams*:

```
out = df.pivot('Date', 'Customer', 'Size')
print(out)

# Output:
Customer    Customer1  Customer2  Customer3
Date                                       
01.01.2021          5          2          6
02.01.2021          5          4          5
```

Now you can plot your dataframe:

```
out.plot.bar(stacked=True, rot=0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

**Update**

> I am asking this, because I want to change figure parameters, and can't find a way to combine your syntax, with the fig, ax=... way.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
out.plot.bar(stacked=True, rot=0, ax=ax)
```

Comment: Trying your example I also received the same error - **Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape**.

Comment: I found the problem. Everything works!

Comment: One final question please - how to convert `out.plot.bar(stacked=True, rot=0)` to something like `plt.bar(out,stacked=True, rot=0)`

Comment: It's not trivial to do that because you have to do it manually. Check https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_stacked.html

Comment: As far I can understand the first variable should be df.index, but can't figure out the other one. The output of the pivot is not flat, so can't understand very well how to access the "customer " column.  `NameError: name 'Customer' is not defined`

Comment: I am asking this, because I want to change figure parameters, and can't find a way to combine your syntax, with the fig, ax=... way.

Comment: Ok. I understood. I updated my answer. Is it ok for you?

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.